# IOS UTM Tracking

Tags: ios, utm

I am facing error while creating UTM code for IOS app tracking. Link is not working. Can someone please help me??
[image: Here is the screenshot]

I am adding all the IOS App details which https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/campaign-url-builder/ios/ site is asking. But my final URL is not working at all.

Comment: can you share the final url?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the error because of the wrong app url provided. The 'redirect url' should be an iTunes URL.

Replace `https://apps.apple.com` with `https://itunes.apple`